# Running Pure Django Projects on Google App Engine - sample zip - django-1.3.1

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I have post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/zi_4jVcPxUo) about which I learned later that gae has moved here.

Basically I tried django-nonrel example, replacing its django with django-1.3.1 since I coded my app on it but it gives some basic error like cannot find django.db.utils.  Note that I have created symbolic link from django -> Django-1.3.1/django and hope its not the issue.

Bases upon replies if I try to use django-nonrel version in my app similar to sample app I get error as below as if its cannot find sqlite3 backend though it mentions as one option in its choices.  Also again utils.py is not found.

--> --> -->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4143, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4049, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 616, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3120, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3024, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2887, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "I:\learn\python\event\djangoappengine\main\main.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "I:\learn\python\event\djangoappengine\main\main.py", line 56, in real_main
    run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 116, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 265, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 160, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 194, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\views\debug.py", line 58, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\views\debug.py", line 109, in get_traceback_html
    frames = self.get_traceback_frames()
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\views\debug.py", line 228, in get_traceback_frames
    pre_context_lineno, pre_context, context_line, post_context = self._get_lines_from_file(filename, lineno, 7, loader, module_name)
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\views\debug.py", line 180, in _get_lines_from_file
    source = loader.get_source(module_name)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2518, in get_source
    full_path, search_path, submodule = self.GetModuleInfo(fullname)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2482, in GetModuleInfo
    submodule, search_path = self.GetParentSearchPath(fullname)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2461, in GetParentSearchPath
    parent_package = self.GetParentPackage(fullname)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2437, in GetParentPackage
    if self.find_module(fullname) is None:
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2045, in find_module
    search_path)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\db\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "I:\learn\python\event\django\db\utils.py", line 49, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' isn't an available database backend. 
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name utils
```

what version of django is compatible with django-nonrel or do I have to do development using django-nonrel instead of Django-1.3.1 ?

As I read more on [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) I feel that there are few modification needed to django code.  Its not straight forward to just use the project as it is.  I need to create abstract model super class and it does not support manytomanyfield which I use in my project.

I guess some one confirm these restriction then probably I can close this thread.

### March 28

I removed M2M from my app.  It was very minor thing just commented out M2M field.
Now I have installed python2.7.2, gae 1.6.4 and djangoappengine gives error as below:

```
E:\learn\python\event>python manage.py runserver
WARNING:root:E:\software\Google\google_appengine\lib\cacerts\urlfetch_cacerts.tx
t missing; without this urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
  File "E:\learn\python\event\settings.py", line 4, in <module>
    from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
  File "E:\learn\python\event\djangoappengine\settings_base.py", line 6, in <mod
ule>
    setup_env()
  File "E:\learn\python\event\djangoappengine\boot.py", line 69, in setup_env
    setup_project()
  File "E:\learn\python\event\djangoappengine\boot.py", line 123, in setup_proje
ct
    from .utils import have_appserver, on_production_server
  File "E:\learn\python\event\djangoappengine\utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    default_partition='dev')[0]
TypeError: LoadAppConfig() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_partition
'
```

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just replace the version of Django in nonrel. It's actually a fork of Django, with a number of customizations.

Comment: Well then when I copy django from sample app into my project area it has problem as below:

Answer (score 0):

Django-1.3.1/Django's database models do not work on Google App Engine.

Django-nonrel implements a backend so that Django models will work on Google App Engine.

So if you want to use Django models, you must use Django-nonrel.  Otherwise, you can use Django for templating/forms, but you need to use Google App Engine's db.Model or ndb.Model based models.

Comment: I am bit confused about your statement that I can use Django for templating/forms.  do you mean that if I do not use django-nonrel and use django1.3.1 I need to use gae db.Model or ndb.Model.

Comment: could you please check the error I posted if you can help resolve ?

Comment: It's definitely some sort of setup problem, but I'm not very clear on where the problem is.  Two things I can think of are a) you didn't install all the required packages - follow instructions here: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine or b) something is missing in your settings.py.  Check the settings.py file that comes with the django-testapp, especially the DATABASES lines, here's the source https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-testapp/src/3dd32705c980/settings.py

Comment: I guess nonrel yet does not support many to many relation ? If so then my project uses it.  please confirm.

Comment: I haven't tried using ManyToManyRelation fields.  According to the nonrel documentation, it seems mention some ManyToManyRelation emulation, but I don't know how well it works.  I've tried using an explicit intermediate mapping table/class, as well as a ListProperty field.  Both work for me, but I'm preferring ListProperties on the most part right now.

Comment: ListProperies will be for 1:N relation and intermediate table is basically converting M:N to 1:N relations.  I actually read some where that many to many is not supported.

Comment: [Supported Features](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#id3) says many to many not supported.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've understood my last comment entirely.  ManyToManyFields are an SQL type relation that don't work in most NoSQL datastores, like App Engine.  You can mimic the functionality.  Any intermediate table has two 1:N mappings, so you can achieve any M:N mapping, though you need an extra query.  A single ListProperty only gives you a 1:N mapping, but you can do a 1:N mapping in the other direction using another ListProperty, or just a ForeignKey.  If you have an app that uses ManyToMany, you have to rework it to use one of the above.

Comment: You might consider Google CloudSQL, it should support normal Django and ManyToManyFields  https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/

Comment: I removed M2M field and have updated the post.  Please see for error.  I will check cloudsql.

Comment: This is turning into another question, you should probably create a new question for this.  I'm still on py2.5 with 1.6.2, and I'm not seeing that problem.  I'll see if I can upgrade to 1.6.4.

Comment: I have created anothe post [here](http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational/browse_thread/thread/ef157285fbf159ae#)